# How to change the query param's name when using asp-for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber">
</div>
<span asp-validation-for="TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
```

And the following ViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{

    public TrackParcelViewModel TrackParcelViewModel { get; set; }
    // TrackParcelViewModel only has TrackingNumber (int)

    // OTher stuff...

}
```

The url used by the form becomes: `../Track?TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber` which is pretty "ugly" and not easily usable, considering that the reason i'm using GET instead of POST is because I want users to easily navigate with the query.

Is there a way to change how the query param is shown?

EDIT:

I thought about not using a model and just adding a parameter in the controller but that removes the ability to validate the user's input..

Comment: asp-for automatically creates the name and value for you. you might want to define them manually then... <input type="text" class="form-control" name="trackingNumber" value="@TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber">

Comment: Already tried that, the asp-validation-for doesn't work anymore. I guess i'll just go with POST :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrap TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber with another property. like below? I never try it before, let me know if it works. :)

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public TrackParcelViewModel TrackParcelViewModel { get; set; }
    // TrackParcelViewModel only has TrackingNumber (int)
    // OTher stuff...

    public int NameYouLike
    {
        get => TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber;
        set => TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires me to add the validation attributes to the "gateaway" property too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `name` attribute and it will make URL like this
`../Track?TrackingNumber=value`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="TrackingNumber" asp-for="TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber">
```

This will break the validation due to difference in name. We can add validation message manually for TrackingNumber field.

```
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TrackingNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

**Complete Code**

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TrackingNumber" asp-for="TrackParcelViewModel.TrackingNumber">
</div>
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TrackingNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: Like I said in the comment, the asp-validation-for doesn't work anymore when changing the name :/